# How do I update the values of a column in a database using another mapping table? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

Imagine I have the following tables

## Table 1

```
id     question_id  tag_id
1           1         10
2           5          8
```

## Table 2 (Mapping table)

```
old_tag_id   new_tag_id
   8             89
   9             90
   10            91
```

Result That I'm trying to achieve:

## Table 1

```
id    question_id   tag_id
1          1          91
2          5          89
```

.
.
(that is, Update the whole table in using a single query, since I have a table consisting of millions of rows)

I tried using subqueries in SQL but I can't seem to handle when the subqueries seem to return more than one row.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.tag_id = b.old_tag_id
SET a.tag_id = b.new_tag_id
```

Comment: Thank you @Fabio. It worked like a charm. Also, can you mention some related learning that you think can boost my querying skills?

Comment: well this was just update query. what about other queries? I simply had no idea of using inner join with update. I want to be able to use them proficiently.

Comment: Youncan refer to the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html, here is also a nice visual explaination of joins https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 t1
join mapping_table t2 on t1.tag_id = t2.old_tag_id
set t1.tag_id = t2.new_tag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 
SET t1.tag_id = (SELECT t2.new_tag_id 
              FROM Table2 t2
              WHERE t1.tag_id = t2.old_tag_id)
```